# ARG Puzzle Gate 15 Help

Tags: mathematics, alternate-reality-game

Me and my group (yes I'm in a group trying to solve this) are currently working on an ARG puzzle and we are stuck. The first image/clue to the entire puzzle is what is seen below. The creator of this puzzle said that this entire image was math related. We are stumped as all hell. THE IMAGES NAME IS LetterLattice.PNG

[image]

We are completely stuck with it. If you want, I can provide the hints that were given to us by the puzzle maker. We have tried many different forms of photoshopping the image. We also see the Red R and the words "RABBITHOLE", "REDHERRING" and "THISISNTITEITHER".

Any help would be greatly appreciated. We've been on this for about 2 hours now and have nothing.

> **HINTS:**
>
> Hint 1 for Gate 15:
>   `The wordsearch isn't all the info.`
>
> Hint 2 for Gate 15: 
>   `I said on an earlier date that this puzzle was created in collaboration with DutChen. I told him what I wanted in the puzzle and he actually created the image. However, DutChen wasn't the only person I collaborated with...`
>
> Hint 3 for  Gate 15:
>   `Omega Member Beyblade returns at liquid fire with returning crowd bug`
>
> Hint 3.1 for Gate 15:
>   `Hint 3 is a cryptic crossword`
>
> Hint 3.2 for Gate 15:
>   `I don't really like "liquid fire". Replace "liquid fire" with "ThatAsh's 8".`
>
> Hint 3.3 for Gate 15: `A [[cryptic crossword]] is a crossword puzzle in which each clue is a word puzzle in and of itself.⁽⁶⁹⁾
>   —Wikipedia`
>
> Hint 3.4 for Gate 15: `Omega Member [Beyblade returns] [at] [ThatAsh's 8] with [returning crowd] [bug].`
>
> Hint 3.5 for Gate 15: `The letters are on lattice points.`
>
> Hint 4 for Gate 15:
>   `The solution to the cryptic crossword is the person I collaborated with.`

Comment: Holllyyy crap that is a large cross word puzzle

Comment: Welcome to puzzling se!

Comment: Do you happen to have the letters on this imnage in radable form (txt file)? I don't want to type all of these by hand

Comment: @yunzen I used automatic text recognition, there might be flaws: https://pastebin.com/PsmnZDdX

Comment: The second line looks like it might lead to https://bit.ly/isthismath . There might be something useful there.

Comment: What is the ARG this is from? This looks like quite the puzzle and I think I might want to try the game. :_=)